# dev_appserver.py: command not found

Tags: python, google-app-engine, ubuntu

Trying to run a python app on Google app engine in Ubuntu like so

```
$ dev_appserver.py helloworld
```

where helloworld contains the file app.yaml

but I am getting this error

> dev_appserver.py: command not found

Answer (score 18, accepted):

After downloading the App Engine source files you will have to add the directory in the path in order to be able to execute that script file.

Open your `.bashrc` file that is located in the home directory and this line with the correct path ([read more](https://askubuntu.com/q/60218/1173)):

```
export PATH=/path/to/google_app_engine/bin:$PATH
```

Comment: It works. Can you help explain why do we need to add this to environment variable?

Comment: You don't have to modify PATH, but the system needs to know how to find the executable you downloaded. I prefer to symlink files in ~/bin (which is in my PATH) to the executables, for example.

Answer (score 6):

This error happens to me after a google software update. Open up GoogleAppEngineLauncher, and it will automatically fix the Command Symlinks so that you can use them again in the terminal. Well, you do have to click OK when the popup appears.

Comment: This answer has saved me more than once.

Comment: Also saved by this answer. But I had to restart my machine.

Answer (score 1):

Although I know that this question is marked resolved, I had the same issue. I tried to add the path to my .bashrc file, as suggested by Lipis, but the problem persisted.

I isolated the problem to needing to create symlinks. Not knowing how to do this, I found a workaround: install the [GoogleAppEngineLauncher-1.9.40-OSX](http://mac.filehorse.com/download-google-app-engine-sdk/) since the installation process gives the option to the user to automatically create symlinks along the way.

Once installed, you'll be able to make use of the deprecated application, but what's important is that you can now use `dev_appserver.py` and `gcloud` commands in the Terminal.